# CSS Collapsing/Hiding divs with no data in <span>

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to display an address which includes the following information: Title, division, address1, address2, town/state/zip, and country (5 seperate lines worth of data).  The problem is sometimes the company may only have the title, address1, and town/state/zip yet other times it may be all but address2.  This is determined upon a db record request server side.  Therefore how can I make my output look proper when some of my labels will be blank?  **I would like div's that contain an empty span to be essentially collapsed/removed.**  My only idea of how was to use jquery and a selector to find all divs with blank spans (since thats all an asp.net label really is) and then remove those divs however this seems like such bad form.  Is there any way to do this with css?  Possible Code would be something like:  $('span:empty:only-child').parent('div').remove();

**Picture Examples** (Ignore spacing/indentation issues which I will fix)

Missing Division, Address2, and Country

[image: Missing Division, Address2, and Country]

All Possible Fields

[image: All Possible Fields]

**The Html**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddressHeader" CssClass="lblBillingAddressHeader" Text="Billing Address:" />
<div style="position:relative; top:150px; left: 113px;">
    <div class="test">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingDivision" CssClass="lblBillingShippingDivisionFont" />
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress2" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress3" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress4" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 300px;
}

.lblBillingShippingDivisionFont {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lblBillingShippingFont {
    font-size: 10.6px;
}
```

Comment: That's not the HTML, that's the .NET code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you restruture your HTML?

**HTML**

```
<div style="position:relative; top:150px; left: 113px;">
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingDivision" CssClass="lblBillingShippingDivisionFont" />
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress2" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress3" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillingAddress4" CssClass="lblBillingShippingFont" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.lblBillingShippingDivisionFont,
.lblBillingShippingFont {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.lblBillingShippingDivisionFont {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lblBillingShippingFont {
    font-size: 10.6px;
}
```

[jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LkFSV/](http://jsfiddle.net/LkFSV/)

Comment: There have been some other posted answers that work however this method is how I wanted to solve it.  I had issues just setting visibility to false server side so this works great.  I know display: block takes up as much width available and then creates a new line.  When there is nothing it just collapses though?  Is this how block works?

Comment: In theory yes - I believe most browsers work that way. However, IE may have some issues with this - it has a bug/quirk where it'll give a minimum of one-line height to empty divs. Sorry, wasn't thinking about IE when I posted this. You may want to include a JS fix as well for IE users.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').each(function() {
           if ($(this).find('span').text() == '') {
             $(this).hide();
           }
        });
      });
```

http://jsbin.com/axaxut/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no parent selectors in CSS. If there was, you could do something like:

```
span:empty:parent { display: none; }
```

Your best bets are the jQuery that you already have or to do it server side, I would personally say that server side is your best option.

Comment: Do you think the simplest way would be to give id's and runat=server to the 5 address divs and then depending upon the query just set certain divs visible property to false?  I can do that I was just hoping there was a way to do this from css

Comment: Yup. No css solution that I know of. You need a parent selector and I don't think there's one even in CSS3. If there is, browser support definitely won't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is asp.net code, you can check from server side code if the address2 is empty and simply hide the control.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblBillingAddress2.Text))
    lblBillingAddress2.Visible = false;
```